# Is it possible to have alternative inheritance in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

**My goal:**

```
class BaseClass1:
    def f(self)

class BaseClass2:
    def f(self)

class DerivedClass:
    def g(self):
        self.f() # this is either BaseClass1::f() or BaseClass2::f(), depending on instantiation
```

Where `DerivedClass` is can be instanced either:

```
class DerivedClass(BaseClass1)
```

or

```
class DerivedClass(BaseClass2)
```

**I understand that this can solve the problem itself:**

```
class UtilityClass1:
    def f(self)

class UtilityClass2:
    def f(self)

class DerivedClass:
    def __init__(self, utilityInstance):
        self.utility = utilityInstance
    def g(self):
        self.utility.f()

d = DerivedClass(UtilityClass1())
d = DerivedClass(UtilityClass2())
```

However, I specifically want to know, if there is another way, through inheritance (probably using some decorators, or whatever).

---

**Just to wrap things up:**

INPUT:
3 class definitions:

```
class BaseClass1
class BaseClass2
class DerivedClass
```

OUTPUT:
2 "merged" class instances:

```
d1 = DerivedClass(BaseClass1)
d2 = DerivedClass(BaseClass2)
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem that __should not__ be solved with inheritance. Stick to composition.

Comment: Yes, I know, but as I have written in the question, I am specifically interested, if it is possible to solve it using inheritance. Let's say this is an academic question:)